# Artemiscloud io - connection from outside cluster

Tags: activemq-artemis, artemiscloud

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis deployed on a Kubernetes cluster. I use the operator https://artemiscloud.io/

This is my deployment scenario:

```
apiVersion: broker.amq.io/v1beta1
kind: ActiveMQArtemis
metadata:
  name: ex-aao
spec:
  adminUser: XXXXXXX
  adminPassword: yyyyyyyy
  deploymentPlan:
    size: 2
    image: placeholder
  console:
    expose: true
    sslEnabled: false
#  connectors:
#    - items:
#      host: 0.0.0.0
#      name: custom-artemis
#      port: 61616
  acceptors:
    - items:
      bindToAllInterfaces: true
      name: artemis
      port: 61616
      protocols: CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE
```

In this way I have 2 pods in which the `broker.xml` content is:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<configuration
    xmlns="urn:activemq"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
    <core
        xmlns="urn:activemq:core"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
        <name>amq-broker</name>
        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
        <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
        <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
        <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
        <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
        <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
        <!-- if you want to retain your journal uncomment this following configuration.

      This will allow your system to keep 7 days of your data, up to 10G. Tweak it accordingly to your use case and capacity.

      it is recommended to use a separate storage unit from the journal for performance considerations.

      <journal-retention-directory period="7" unit="DAYS" storage-limit="10G">data/retention</journal-retention-directory>

      You can also enable retention by using the argument journal-retention on the `artemis create` command -->
        <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
        <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
        <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
        <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
        <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
        <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->
        <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->
        <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
        <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->
        <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
        <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->
        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->
        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->
        <connectors>
            <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
            <connector name="artemis">tcp://ex-aao-ss-0.ex-aao-hdls-svc.activemq-artemis-operator.svc.cluster.local:61616</connector>
        </connectors>
        <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
        <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
        <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
        <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
        <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
        <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
        <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit. This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

      The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
      You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

      <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size> -->
        <!-- the maximum number of messages accepted before entering full address mode.
           if global-max-size is specified the full address mode will be specified by whatever hits it first. -->
        <global-max-messages>-1</global-max-messages>
        <acceptors>
            <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
            <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
            <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
            <!-- amqpDuplicateDetection: If you are not using duplicate detection, set this to false
                                      as duplicate detection requires applicationProperties to be parsed on the server. -->
            <!-- amqpMinLargeMessageSize: Determines how many bytes are considered large, so we start using files to hold their data.
                                       default: 102400, -1 would mean to disable large mesasge control -->
            <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->
            <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
            <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61626?protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpMinCredits=300</acceptor>
            <acceptor name="scaleDown">tcp://ex-aao-ss-0.ex-aao-hdls-svc.activemq-artemis-operator.svc.cluster.local:61616?protocols=CORE;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpMinCredits=300</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
        <cluster-user>cYhlW3ah</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>08V103rH</cluster-password>
        <broadcast-groups>
            <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
                <jgroups-file>jgroups-ping.xml</jgroups-file>
                <jgroups-channel>activemq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
                <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>
        <discovery-groups>
            <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
                <jgroups-file>jgroups-ping.xml</jgroups-file>
                <jgroups-channel>activemq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
                <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
            </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>
        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
                <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
                <retry-interval-multiplier>2</retry-interval-multiplier>
                <max-retry-interval>32000</max-retry-interval>
                <initial-connect-attempts>20</initial-connect-attempts>
                <reconnect-attempts>10</reconnect-attempts>
                <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
                <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>
        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin"/>
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin"/>
                <permission type="consume" roles="admin"/>
                <permission type="browse" roles="admin"/>
                <permission type="send" roles="admin"/>
                <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
                <permission type="manage" roles="admin"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>
        <address-settings>
            <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>
            <!--default for catch all-->
            <address-setting match="#">
                <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <!-- if max-size-bytes and max-size-messages were both enabled, the system will enter into paging
                 based on the first attribute to hits the maximum value -->
                <!-- limit for the address in bytes, -1 means unlimited -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <!-- limit for the address in messages, -1 means unlimited -->
                <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
                <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>
        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
        </addresses>
        <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins><broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin"><property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/><property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/><property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/><property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/><property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/><property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/><property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/></broker-plugin></broker-plugins>
      -->
    </core>
```

I have a Spring Boot JMS producer and consumer. I'm not able to connect this Spring Boot application from outside of Kubernetes cluster.
I'm struggling in finding the right configuration that allows to me to connect to the broker by using a laptop (developer laptop). May anybody suggest me how to achieve this result?
The web console, instead, is correctly shown by using the ingresses created by the operator.

Comment: Have you tried exposing the acceptor with `expose: true`?